# For Python Cython wrapper of C/C++ library, how to delegate object's instantiation back to additional C++ code and expose it back to python

Tags: python, c++, cython

In my python project (let's call it project **A**) I use a C++ project (let's call it project **B**) that exposes C++ API, and also provides python wrapper, that is created with Cython. In the project **A**, I have a time consuming algorithm that builds an object from project's **B** python API using different functions from the same API, and uses said object afterwards throughout the code. I'm trying to find a way to delegate object building part to C/C++, but for now have no idea how to approach it. I can't modify project's **B** internal code, so I can't add this object building functionality to C++ codebase and expose it along with API in the Cython part, so I think, I need to create this object in C++, using project's **B** C++ API, than I somehow need to pass this object to the python code but in a way so it is still compatible with python API of project **B**. I don't have a lot of experience with Cython so I'm not even sure if it is even possible (without reconstructing full python API just to add my algorithm)?